# No symbol in debugger, xCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios4, gdb

Hi I'am running a debug build with **NO** optimizations and "*DWARF with dSYM file*" as debugging format. Why can't I print my dictionary to console? Have I missed something? xCode version is 4.0.2 and Iam using LLVM 2.9 svn version with GDB debugger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say that I know for sure, but here are a few things to try...

1. Try "po [dict description]"
2. Try cleaning before you compile in case old symbols file stuck around for some reason
3. Are you attaching the debugger after launch?  I've had problems with this.
4. Is this breakpoint firing during the launch?  Also had problems with this.
5. Can you print anything else?
6. Try inserting an "NSLog(@"%@", [dict description])" in there.
7. Is your SessionManager *for certain* returning something that is both a) not nil and b) responds to the selector "description:"?  If not you may get nothing.

Looking at your log, my first guess is that you're breaking before the debugger has had a chance to attach properly.  Totally a guess, but try the NSLog thing and see if you get output.

Comment: How can you say he's breaking before the debugger had a chance to attach properly? I see Attaching to process 1512 in the log.

Comment: @Black Frog - Yeah I saw it, just a possibility.  I've had the debugger lie to me before.  Most of the time the issues I've seen seem to be with waiting to attach until after launch.  Another time I've seen weirdness has been debugging during the launch sequence.  Just one thing I'd suggest examining based on my own experiences.  YMMV.

Comment: po [dict description] returned the same error. I made a clean build, and I am running debug build with breakpoints, so I dont attach the process manually. In the debug view, if I choose "Local" I can see self, input parameters and NSError, but not the dictionary. I can also print the dictionary with NSlog without any problems.

Comment: @Konrad77 - The most common reason is of course having optimizations turned on.  You say you're certain you don't, so I'm just spit-balling ideas here.  Have you tried changing the compiler back to GDB?  Optimization level is definitely "None [-O0]" for Debug?  LLVM integration with Xcode is still a little shaky, so it wouldn't surprise me if it was just a bug.

Comment: Thanks DougW. Switching to GCC helped. I was home yesterday, thats why I couldn't check your suggestion until now. +1 from me!

Comment: @Konrad77 - D'oh, yes I meant "GCC" not "GDB".  Too many acronyms!  Glad that worked.  I would consider switching back to LLVM after you get your problem sorted out.  The integration with Xcode is still young, but it's a much better/newer compiler.  Cheers!